# I am trying to calculate an age based on birthdate given and the current date in c

Tags: c, date

I am creating a program in c for my unix course.  I am trying to create a function that finds the current date, takes the individuals birthdate (stored in the **individual string), and use them to calculate the individuals age in years and months.  I am not sure about how to go about this since current date is stored in a struct tm while the individuals birthday is stored in a string.  (very new to c, only been learning it for a few days).  Below is my code for this function if somebody can please give me some advice, thank you.

```
char* calcage(char **individual, char **age)
{
    time_t time_raw_format;
    struct tm * time_struct;
    char *lastname = (char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    char *lnamefile = (char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    char buf [100];

    time ( &time_raw_format );
    time_struct = localtime ( &time_raw_format );

    strftime (buf,100,"It is: %m/%d/%Y.",time_struct);
    puts (buf);

    printf("person: %s\n", *individual);

    lastname = strrchr(*individual, ',');
    lastname++;
    //lnamefile = strtok(lastname, searchseperator);
    printf("Individual:  %s\n", lastname);

  }
```

Comment: Convert the date in the string to a time, then do whatever calculations you need to do.

Comment: Suggest `struct tm time_struct; time_struct = *localtime ( &time_raw_format );`

Answer (score 0):

The typical route here is to bring both dates into a canonical timestamp format.
For parsing the string, see: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Date-and-Time.html

Once you have both of the formats in UNIX timestamp format, you can substract and then convert back into years. There are some caveats though:

- The conversion back into years is not accurate if you just assume 365 days per year due to leap years. This is a very subtle effect that will make the calculation wrong in very few cases (commonly referred to as "at the customer").
- UNIX timestamps start in 1970 and people were born before that. Better timestamp formats exist.

So in the end, it might be worthwile to extract the date, month and year, then compare them individually.

Comment: I am trying to use the strptim to convert the string to time but for some reason it doesn't like my last line in the function but im not sure why.  

    char* calcage(char **individual, char **age)
    {
      time_t time_raw_format;
      struct tm * time_struct;
      char *birthday = (char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
      struct tm * birthparse;
      struct tm * birth_struct;

     birthparse = strptime(birthday, "%D", birth_struct);
}

Comment: In the past, when I've needed a wider range than the Unix date values, I've used Julian/Astronomical Day Number. It allows for historical adjustments in "our" calendar, and has an epoch date of some time around 4000 BC. (I haven't checked whether that is deliberately synched with Usher's calculation, but I've assumed so.)